# Monitor most recent folder for changes in TeamCity

Tags: git, version-control, github, continuous-integration, teamcity

I am working on setting up CI for my website using TeamCity 8. For the web site, this is easy as I just copy out the whole folder.

But for our SQL updates, we have it set up such that with each release, we have a separate folder. For example:

```
db
  update
    001
    002
    003
    ...
    018
```

So I'm trying to figure out how to set up the version control settings step to only monitor the last folder for changes. Worst case, I can just monitor the whole update tree for changes since, theoretically, we should only be making changes to the last folder.

But figuring how how to point to the last folder will be cleaner because a) it will prevent triggering the build from accidental changes to previous folders, and b) it will allow a single local path from which to run the scripts every time (without having another piece of logic to figure out which path to run).

This may not be possible though, so reaching out to the community. If it matters, our VCS is Git/Github.

Comment: How are the 001-XXX folders created? Are they done manually?

Comment: Yeah, just following each release whenever the developers start working on a new release (probably whoever needs to add the first DB script). I was trying to avoid another manual process, i.e. updating the TeamCity build steps.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a structure like:

```
db
  update
    001
    002
    003
    004
    ...
    current
```

Then inside the current folder is like:

```
004-Script-1.sql
004-Script-2.sql
004-Script-3.sql
```

Your TC build would then run any script in the `current` folder and then move the script based off the first part of the name to the corresponding folder. You would have to in order:

1. Make the folder if it doesn't exist.
2. Move the files into the correct folders
3. Do a git pull, commit all modified files and push

This is assuming you wouldn't re-run the scripts multiple times on that environment and that the committers **only** commit and push files into the current folder that are to be run following the right name syntax. Otherwise you could end up with all sorts of random folder names.

Alternatively you could use bash to find the highest folder name in that folder and just run everything inside of that (Below assumes you are in the upload directory):

```
$ ls
001    002    003    004    005    026    124    204
$ LAST=`exec ls | sed 's/\([0-9]\+\).*/\1/g' | sort -n | tail -1`
$ echo $LAST
204
```

This would assume everything in the highest folder is to be run, and re-run unless you worked logic in.

Answer (score 0):

You could define build-parameter by name which can look like : cur.release.folder.numbeer & ask it to prompt if user tries to force the build to run on specific folder.

```
Trigger rules: +:/db/update/%cur.release.folder.number%/**
```

**OR**

Whenever you manually create the folder, add a logic in your project to set a property by name cur.release.folder.number & in build steps of teamcity, handle it with additional step.

build step #1 will calculate latest folder-number may be with a simple shell script . You can use 
`-Dparamname=%teamcity.build.checkoutDir%/tmpFileHoldingFolderNoInfo.txt`

build step #2: use same in trigger rules as above - with default set to empty & use the value from step#1